# How do I stop the slider content from hiding?

Tags: html

I am currently trying to figure out how to stop slider section content from disappearing. I tried to remove the "data-hide-transition" & "data-hide-delay" from the code, but still no luck.

Below I have included code for the slider section. I would really appreciate, if some could let me know what the problem & solution could be.

```html
<section class="section-header-slider">
    <div class="slider-pro-init vertical-slider" data-orientation="vertical" data-buttons-control="true" data-arrows-control="false">
        <div class="sp-slides">
            <div class="slide-item dark sp-slide">
                <div class="slide-image">
                    <img src="img/sections/section-11.jpg"  alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide-content right-slide-content dark-content">
                    <div class="above-title sp-layer" data-show-transition="left" data-hide-transition="" data-show-delay="400" data-hide-delay="" >we are CreativeBrick.</div>
                    <h1 class="sp-layer" data-show-transition="right" data-show-delay="500" >Real Estate Marketing</h1>
                    <p class="sp-layer" data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="up" data-show-delay="600" data-hide-delay="5100">With over a decade of experience, we have helped our clients all over the world  <br />
                            to create eye-catching and beautiful solutions for their business.</p>
                    <div class="slider-buttons sp-layer" data-show-transition="up" data-hide-transition="up" data-show-delay="800" data-hide-delay="5100">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-transparent active">get started</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-transparent">purchase</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```